# how to capture graphics primitives from Graphics2D into SVG

Tags: java, svg, graphics2d

I need to capture the graphics primitives from calls to java.awt.Graphics2D. The calls are made through an Open Source toolkit (Apache's PDFBox) and normally rendered in a JPanel. I would like to intercept these calls and translate them to SVG so I can build a non-graphics data model (e.g. tables, graphs, etc.). I'll be happy for any type of hack at this stage, which might include:

- replacing the Graphics2D library with MyGraphics2D
- Finding a Graphics2D that supported SVG output and capturing that
- intercepting the calls to Graphics2D (I'd prefer not because I have to manage the affine transformations)

Subsidiary question: Does Graphics2D use the Graphics library? In which case if I capture at this level the transformations should have been applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at the [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html) project which provides an extension of Graphics2D to output SVG files.

Comment: Good idea. I have used Batik a long time ago and hopefully it's worth revisiting

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) is another option to consider, it provides a [fast](http://www.object-refinery.com/blog/blog-20140423.html) lightweight implementation of the Graphics2D API.