# Parsing a string to a shape

Tags: java, awt, filestream, paint, java-2d

I'm making a paint application, and for the input of the shapes that were saved, I came across an issue.

You see, I am using a while loop to run through each line of a string saved by the program at an earlier time. I also have identifiers of what it is currently inputting. I had the program output the List of the shapes as what they are. Meaning, that each shape would output like `java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float@15990000`.

Now I need some sort of way to turn that String, back into a shape. Either that, or have some sort of way to save it as a shape, in an easier way, that would allow me to add it right back to the List

Any and all help would be welcomed.

Comment: Consider serializing your list of Shapes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and how would I do that?

Comment: It allows you to store the desired information as binary data, and then allowing you at a later time to read the binary data and unmarshal it back into objects. Telling the details would involve me re-writing tutorials that are already out there, and so I invite you to Google some and to check them out. Note that the text information that you're currently displaying, `java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float@15990000` is simply the default result returned by calling `toString()` and does not hold enough info to allow you to reproduce your shapes.

Comment: There are also text-based solutions involving XML such as XMLEncoder for Java Beans and JAXB, but each has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) or a subset of it for the format of the saved files. If you use SVG, you can check (or use) [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) - it can transform SVG into Java2D objects.

This might be also interesting: [how to capture graphics primitives from Graphics2D into SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989256/how-to-capture-graphics-primitives-from-graphics2d-into-svg)